# Why can't detect the bigger JavaScript String in Array?

Tags: javascript

This is a part from my code.I'm doing a javascript exercise.

```
switch(size) {
   case "big":
        var nameSize = "";
        if(fNames[i].length > nameSize.length) {
            nameSize = fNames[i];
        }
        console.log("Your Female Big: " + nameSize);
   break;
```

The user chooses the name with "big" size (the biggger string in array)  through  a `prompt()`. I trying to verify if `fNames[i]` is the bigger string in my array `fNames` to return for the user, but isnt working, **it is return all strings.**. What am I doing wrong?

#### ----> [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AF7u/2/)

### Update

This code works:

```
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = 0;
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);
```

(from codecademy)

It is the same logic, i think. Why my code does not work, then?

Comment: Casing issue perhaps: `"Big"` and `"big"`?

Comment: The second example works because you're comparing the size of the value of the variable, not the length

Comment: @rednaw In my code I use `length` to get around this. It should work, no?
@kei Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant. But it's the same thing.

Comment: Can you show us more code? Where is `i` declared?

Comment: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AF7u/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add `.length`:

```
nameSize = fNames[i].length;
```

If this is happening inside a loop you should check the length of the biggest compared to the var in the loop:

```
var name = '';
if(fNames[i].length > name.length) {
    name = fNames[i];
}
```

Notice that in the `if` you use `.length` on both the variables.

Comment: That is return "The big name: 7", for example. I want the name, not the number length. The number length is just for verifying.

Comment: Then you have to track the index of the biggest one, not only the "size"

Comment: How do you mean "all the strings"? `name` should now contain the biggest string.

Comment: All the strings of my array `fNames = ["Cersei", "Jane"]`. i want to return the bigger, but it is returning all.

Comment: The result is: `Your Female Big: Cersei` `Your Female Big: Jane`. I want just the bigger: `Your Female Big: Cersei`"

Comment: Did you put `var nameSize = "";` OUTSIDE the loop?

Comment: @rednaw No. I was doing wrong. Now I did this and it almost worked. I added a jsFiddle.

Comment: In the jsfiddle you still didn't add the `.length` on the `nameSize`.